# Is it possible to query file's properties?

Tags: google-drive-api

Are custom file properties queryable on files.list requests? I would like to filter out files with certain properties with queries such as `property = 'tested'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching for properties is not possible at the moment, but it's a feature on our roadmap. We'd like to provide `in` queries for key, value and visibility.

Comment: Is there a ticket for this issue, or any update as to when/if it might be available?